# Use reusable mapping, oracle odi 12c

Tags: oracle, integration, oracle12c

I'm starting to use the ODI 12C, have a base of 11G, from what I saw there is no way to create a direct database table, like the yellow interfaces.

Is there something like that? Reusable mapping do it?

There is as indicate a short tutorial explaining how to make use of this mapping using reusable because using table already created already worked?

Since already appreciate the attention.

Answer (score 0):

A mapping is an equivalent of 11G interface. You just pull the table on there and it can work as either source or target depending on where the table is in the flow. Also, a mapping unlike an 11G interface can have many targets.

A reusable mapping is a part of a mapping (set of transformation) that you can isolate and reuse across other mappings. Though, it is not very useful, cause it has to have a fixed and defined set of input and output columns. That's often not the case when you repeat a set of transformations for many source tables each having a different number of columns.

Comment: OK, but is there any way to create the runtime table, like the yellow interfaces?
Because from what I saw, it is mandatory that the origin and the destination are already created.
It does not make the ODI own create the tables in the database?

Comment: What odi does depends on the knowledge module for given transformation